# How to fix duplicated documents in Elasticsearch when indexing by Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using the Elastic Stack to handle my log files but is generating duplicated documents in the Elasticsearch.

I've made some survey and already tried to add the "document_id", but it did not solve.

This is the configuration of my Logstash:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {

  fingerprint {
    source => "message"
    target => "[fingerprint]"
    method => "SHA1"
    key => "key"
    base64encode => true
  } 

  if [doctype] == "audit-log" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "^\(%{GREEDYDATA:loguser}@%{IPV4:logip}\) \[%{DATESTAMP:logtimestamp}\] %{JAVALOGMESSAGE:logmessage}$" }
    }
    mutate {
      remove_field => ["host"]
    }
    date {
      match => [ "logtimestamp" , "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ]
      target => "@timestamp"
      locale => "EU"
      timezone => "America/Sao_Paulo"
    } 
  }  

}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "192.168.0.200:9200"
    document_id => "%{[fingerprint]}"
  }
}
```

Here the duplicated documents:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2019.05.02-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "EbncP00tf9yMxXoEBU4BgAAX/gc=",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "fingerprint": "EbncP00tf9yMxXoEBU4BgAAX/gc=",
    "message": "(thiago.alves@192.168.0.200) [06/05/2019 18:50:08] Logout do usuário 'thiago.alves'. (cookie=9d6e545860c24a9b8e3004e5b2dba4a6). IP=192.168.0.200",
    ...
}

######### DUPLICATED #########

{
  "_index": "logstash-2019.05.02-000001",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "V7ogj2oB8pjEaraQT_cg",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "fingerprint": "EbncP00tf9yMxXoEBU4BgAAX/gc=",
    "message": "(thiago.alves@192.168.0.200) [06/05/2019 18:50:08] Logout do usuário 'thiago.alves'. (cookie=9d6e545860c24a9b8e3004e5b2dba4a6). IP=192.168.0.200",
    ...
}
```

That's it. I don't know why is duplicating yet. Someone have any idea?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: I'm surprised to see the square brackets around fingerprint. Have you tried setting the document_id to "%{fingerprint}"?

Comment: I second @JoeZack, you need to use the fingerprint as the document ID and the problem will be solved

Comment: Firstly, thank you for help. I've tried to use the fingerprint without the square brackets, but unfortunately the problem continues... Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem once and after many attempts to solve it, I realized that I did a backup for my conf file into 'pipeline' folder and Logstash was using this backup file to process input rules. Be careful because Logstash will use others files in pipeline folder even the file extension is different from '.conf'.

So, please check if do you have others files in the 'pipeline' folder.

Please let me know if this was useful to you.

Comment: OMG!!! Very good! I really had another file in the pipeline directory, but I didn't know that Logstash was considering it. I has removed the other file and the problem has solved. Very thank you. Congratulations!!!

Answer (score 1):

Generate a UUID key for each document then your issue will be solved.

Comment: We've faced an issue similar to OP's and setting up and UUID in fact solved our issue. The logstash-filter-uuid works fine, but basically any kind of ID generating method works as long as you use the document_id parameter in the Elasticsearch output as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.3/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id

Comment: Firstly, thank you for help. I've tried to use the UUID, but unfortunately the problem continues...

Here the link that I followed: [logstash-lessons-handling-duplicates](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-lessons-handling-duplicates)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine and shouldn't allow duplicates, maybe the duplicated one was added before you added `document_id => "%{[fingerprint]}"` to your logstash, so elasticsearch generated a unique Id for it that wont be overriden by other ids, remove the duplicated (the one having _id different than fingerprint) manually and try again, it should work.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for help. I am indexing from a log file and every document that is indexed is duplicating, I don't know how to try again with the same document. Thank you.

Comment: Delete the whole index then and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed that Logstash 7.5.2 is not working properly, It duplicates the logs which are coming from the Filebeat. The actual issue we noticed the inbuild Beats plugin has a bug. So we removed the existing one and updated it to the stable version (6.0.14). The steps are as below,

[download](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-input-beats/versions/6.1.4-java)

./bin/logstash-plugin remove logstash-input-beats

./bin/logstash-plugin install /{file path}/logstash-input-beats-6.0.14-java.gem

./bin/logstash-plugin list --verbose